# Issues after updated to Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I had my iOS App up to 98% completed on Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 and it's working OK.

But then problems begin when I try to update my Xcode to version 5 and the SDK to iOS 7.

When I try to run the app on Xcode 5 but with iOS 6.1 it continues working ok, but when I tried to run on SDK 7 I have these issues:

```
2013-12-17 19:44:47.656 myAPP[2207:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MKUserLocation 0x9d9af90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key distanceAnnotation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01bf65e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019798b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c866a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0142d8ca -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x0139a921 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 81
    5   Foundation                          0x01399f5b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 260
    6   Foundation                          0x013b9a5a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 409
    7   Foundation                          0x013c68c6 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 380
    8   Foundation                          0x013c66d7 -[NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] + 578
    9   myapp
                        0x00009e50 -[mapa mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:] + 496
    10  MapKit                              0x0037e974 -[MKMapView mapViewDidFinishLoadingTiles:] + 78
    11  VectorKit                           0x050a3ade -[VKMapView mapDidFinishLoadingTiles:] + 78
    12  VectorKit                           0x050abe4e -[VKMapCanvas mapModelDidFinishLoadingTiles:] + 46
    13  VectorKit                           0x050b82cd -[VKMapModel didStopLoadingTilesWithError:] + 77
    14  VectorKit                           0x051ae2e1 -[VKTileProvider didStopLoadingTilesWithError:] + 49
    15  VectorKit                           0x051b1c99 -[VKTileSource didFinishWithNetwork] + 73
    16  VectorKit                           0x051c3aa3 __41-[VKResourcesTileSource performDownload:]_block_invoke73 + 51
    17  GeoServices                         0x04bb98a6 ___ZNK49-[GEOTileLoaderInternal _loadedTile:forKey:info:]66__49-[GEOTileLoaderInternal _loadedTile:forKey:info:]_block_invoke3$_1clERKN8LoadItem9RequesterE_block_invoke_2 + 85
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x021f77f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0220c4b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x021fa75e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01c5ba5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01b9c6bb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01b9bac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01b9b8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x033579e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x03357809 GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x004dad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  FarmValencia                        0x000029ad main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0249e70d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please post code that resulted in this stack trace.

Comment: Might be because you are not referencing/including the Core Location framework in your project. According to this guide "Location services are provided by the Core Location framework. Maps are provided by the Map Kit framework." The stack trace shows MapKit but no CoreLocation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Theres simply not enough information to correctly debug this item.

I can recommend however that you add a Breakpoint for all Exceptions

Here is an example of adding an All Exception breakpoint in XCode 4. The process is the same in XCode 5

http://www.alauda.ro/2013/02/03/xcode-4-exception-breakpoints/

Aside from that you may try working with NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

This will allow you to trap the error and output the results but bear in mind that this is something you should only do during debug.

Wrapping it in an "#if DEBUG" is a good idea.

I hope this helps you out. These kind of bugs are a pain to fix.

**NOTE**

You may check if the key value set you are using didn't change between SDK's

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance sending the message valueForUndefinedKey: to the class MKUserLocation?

Here's what the class reference says about getting user location:

"The MKUserLocation class defines a specific type of annotation that identifies the user’s current location. You do not create instances of this class directly. Instead, you retrieve an existing MKUserLocation object from the userLocation property of the map view displayed in your application."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html